# jquery .attr not working wih jsp custom tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using a number of my own custom tags on my jsp page.My issue is the jquery .attr function is not returning proper values for any of the new attributes i have added to my custom tags.
For eg.if my tag is as shown below

```
<bb:inputtext id="selMetric" value="swf1" addOnText="Chart:" onblur="sayHello();" title="mytitle"></bb:inputtext>
```

component.attr('title') will work but component.attr('addOnText') will be undefined.Can anyone tell me what can be the reason?

Thanks in advance,
Dipti.

Answer (score 1):

try to use data tags as stated in the html5 spec instead of creating new custom tags 
e.g.:

```
data-addOnText="value"
```

then you can access the data using `$('element').data('addOnText');`
it might be that your template creator simply filters out unrecognized attributes

here's a good article about it:
http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

You should view the actual source not the jsp. Javascript is client-side, not server, so you have to define component variable to match the real source browser sees.